# Binding within a UserControl not working (templatebinding to a custom dependency property)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a user control which I'd like to be used like so:

```
// MainPage.xaml
<my:MyControl Data="10" />
<!-- or -->
<my:MyControl Data="{Binding SomeData}" />
```

It's codebind is this:

```
 public partial class MyControl : UserControl
 {
    public MyControl() {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
   public const string DataPropertyName = "Data";
   public int Data
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(DataProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(DataProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            DataPropertyName,
            typeof(int),
            typeof(MyControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(10);
 }
```

It's xaml portion is this:

```
 <UserControl>
    <!-- omitted namespaces etc. -->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
         <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="{Binding Data}">
           <Button.Style>
             <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                 </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
            </Button.Style>
         </Button>
    </Grid>
   </UserControl>
```

The crucial line, in usercontrol's xaml part is:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="{Binding Data}">
```

I'd like to bind this Button's Content property to the UserControl's property (Data), while still retaining the ability to set values on it from outside (`<my:MyControl Data="10" />`)

The problem is, that when I use binding - `<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="{Binding Data}">` - it doesn't work (The templatebinding doesnt pick any values)
It works however, if I set the values manually i.e - `<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="12">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to bind to your "own" dependency property inside a `UserControl` you need to add a `x:Name` to your `UserControl` and use it as the `ElementName` in your binding.

```
<UserControl x:Name="myControl">
    <!-- omitted namespaces etc. -->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
         <Button x:Name="myButton" 
                 Content="{Binding Data, ElementName=myControl}">        
         </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

To make the `Template` also work:

Instead of the `TemplateBinding` you need to use the `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` sysntax, because you need to set the `Mode=OneWay` (TemplateBinding uses `Mode=OneTime` for performance reasons by default but in your scenario you need `Mode=OneWay`)

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=OneWay, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </ControlTemplate>    
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tried it - but it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the templatebinding not picking any values. I've also tried creating a binding programatically as well as adding a callback to the DependencyProperty where I manually set the button's content, but that also didn't work.

Comment: @zyash yes, you are right the problem is with the templatebinding, see my updated answer.

Comment: I had to edit the RelativeSource binding slightly, to get it to work. I found an example on the [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent(v=vs.110).aspx)
So I changed the Text binding to Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value}"
Then it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction..

Comment: @Daisy The `Path=Value` depends on the `TargetType`. In my answer I have `TargetType="Button"` which has a property `Content` so I used `Path=Content`. In your linked article they have `TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}"` which does not have Content but has a Value so they use  `Path=Value`